# How to pause/resume transfer of large files?

Tags: nautilus, command-line, clipboard

I recently had to copy about 20 GB of data split between about 20 files from my laptop to an external hard drive. Since this operation takes quite a while (at ~560kb/s), I was wondering if there was any way to pause the transfer and resume it later (in case, I need to interrupt the transfer). As a side question, is there any performance difference between copying from the terminal vs copying from Nautilus?

Answer (score 28):

I would recommened using [rsync](http://samba.anu.edu.au/rsync/documentation.html).

Example:

`rsync -a --append source-file destination`

If you want to see the progress, add the `--progress` option to the command.

[image]

Comment: The **-append** option seems to be the lynch-pin to the "Resume"...  but is there an elegant way to "Pause" *rsync*, other than Ctrl+C? ... and can *rsync* resume accurately, after something dramatic.. eg. a power-out?

Comment: If from coming from google in 2016, one way would be to launch the rsync command as a process from python or similar and monitor the process while reading its output. Then you can trigger a SIG/signal against the process. A sh file should be able to do this i would think

Answer (score 4):

short answer, need no installation,
to pause use `kill -STOP PID`

to continue paused process use `kill -CONT PID`
where PID is Process ID. you can get PID by running System monitor or `top` command

Answer (score 2):

I can answer only the part about the difference between terminal and nautilus. I have checked several times this. It appears copying from terminal is faster than any graphical way like nautilus. At least in my case, when i copy about 32GB of info, it takes about 3 to 5 minutes less from terminal than nautilus from a 25 minute copy. that is about 10%-20% of the time. About a way to resume a copy to your external unit i think `curl` or `rsync` would resume a failed copy. At least with cp command. I have not tried this myself (I will try tomorrow) but this two might work.

For curl you need to `aptitude install curl` or `apt-get instal curl` since it does not come with ubuntu by default.

Use `curl --help` or `rsync --help` to find out more. Tomorrow i will show how to copy with both if you could not find the way.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend rsync, but with the `--partial` option, this way it checks the already transferred data. You could even use it to repair a more or less fully transferred file which has a corruption somewhere in between.

```
rsync -v --info=progress2 --partial source destination
```