# How to show the transfer progress and speed when copying files with cp?

Tags: command-line, coreutils

Otherwise, is there any alternative command line utility that can achieve this?

Comment: Duplicate question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65077/is-it-possible-to-see-cp-speed-and-percent-copied

Comment: In case you already started the `cp` command, and don't want to stop it now, you can `watch` the size of the destination grow like this: https://askubuntu.com/a/1275972/327339 (`watch 'du -hs'`), to know it's really growing and the copy is working.

Answer (score 406, accepted):

While `cp` hasn't got this functionality, you can use `pv` to do this:

```
pv my_big_file > backup/my_big_file
```

Note: this method will lose the file's permissions and ownership. Files copied this way will have the same permissions as if you'd created them yourself and will belong to you.

In this example, `pv` basically just outputs the file to stdout*, which you redirect to a file using the `>` operator. Simultaneously, it prints information about the progress to the terminal when you do that.

This is what it looks like:

```
stefano@ubuntu:~/Data$ pv my_big_file > backup/my_big_file
 138MB 0:00:01 [73.3MB/s] [=================================>] 100%
```

You may need to [Install pv](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/pv) (alternatively, type `sudo apt-get install pv`) on your system.

---

*: **The technical bit**

There are three important streams of data in a unix-like system: stdout (standard output), stderr (standard error) and stdin (standard input). Every program has all three, so to speak. The `>` redirection operator redirects program output to a file. Without arguments, as you see above, `>` redirects a program's *standard output* to a file. `cp` basically does nothing fancier than

```
cat source > destination
```

(where `cat` just reads a file and prints it to stdout). `pv` is just like cat, but if you redirect it's output stream somewhere else, it will print progress information to stdout instead.

Take a look at `man pv` to learn more about it.

---

Another option, as DoR suggests in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17274/how-to-pause-resume-transfer-of-large-files/17280#17280), is to use rsync instead:

```
$ rsync -ah --progress source-file destination-file
sending incremental file list
source-file
        621.22M  57%  283.86MB/s    0:00:01
```

This will preserve the files permissions/ownership while showing progress.

Comment: It may or may no be significant (depending on the situation), but `pv` does not handle permissions the same way as `cp` does... (based on one quick test I tried: `pv` didn't copy the execute bit across.. `rsync` did.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me fred.beak, I didn't think to put that in.

Comment: IMO: `alias cp="rsync -avz"` cp is outdated.

Comment: If you're like me, and forget about `pv`, you can go snooping in `/proc/PID of cp/fd` and `/proc/PID of cp/fdinfo` to figure out progress. (It's up to you to infer speed.) I use this technique to watch `updatedb`.

Comment: for a man of pv without installing it see [here](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pv)

Comment: @MarcoCeppi I copied you alias to my dot file but that didn't work out very well. `-z` makes copying files 3 times slower on my computer so I delete that option.

Comment: Yes, `-z` should probably only be used for network copies; compressing and decompressing the data for a local copy is pure overhead.

Comment: Like `cat`, `pv` is not a good tool for copying sparse files since [it will expand them by filling in any gaps with zero-bytes](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/30382/48446). This means that the new file can take up considerably more disk space despite having the same content as the original.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi , when copying directory with `rsync` be sure not to add trailing `/` to source path (or remove if e.g. bash completion put it there automatically). Otherwise you will get results different than when using `cp` (or `gcp`).

Comment: if `alias cp="rsync -avz"` is outdated, what about `alias cp="rsync -ah --progress source-file"` instead?

Comment: @MarcoCeppi `alias mv="rsync -avz --remove-sent-files"` is nice, too.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi `rsync -avz` is not showing progress on Debian Jessie.

Comment: @Rodrigo `rsync -avzP` is what you'll want to use.

Comment: @MarcoCeppi Thank you! Just wonder why they don't keep all the options sorted in the manual...

Comment: @StefanoPalazzo Nice. For all the MacOS fools out there, this is also available by default.

Comment: Both these options will show the speed at which kernel buffers are filled in with the file bytes. When that operation is complete the buffers will most likely still have data to be written to the disk. In some cases, probably most (like copying a 2.7 Gb file to a not-so-fast USB dongle), flushing that data will take most of the time. You can verify this by running `time sync` right after the `pv`/`rsync` command.

Answer (score 465):

There isn't. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15655/why-doesnt-cp-have-a-progress-bar-like-wget) as to why. Although it does more than you need, `rsync` has a `--progress` parameter. The `-a` will keep permissions,etc, and `-h` will be human readable.

```
rsync -ah --progress source destination
```

The output will look something like this:

```
Pictures/1.jpg
      2.13M 100%    2.28MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#5898, to-chk=1/5905)
Pictures/2.jpg
      1.68M 100%    1.76MB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#5899, to-chk=0/5905)
```

Comment: This works great in the current Ubuntu (14.10). It also supports the `-r` flag to recurse directories. It can even be aliased as a direct replacement for cp: `alias cp="rsync -ah --progress"`

Comment: Works swell on OS X, with the bonus of being able to use tools included with the system.

Comment: this is great, the output looks like `filename MB-copied MB-speed time-remaining)`

Comment: i like this alternative better than pv, specially because rsync is part of the standard install

Comment: @bartekbrak thanks for sharing.  I'm presently on macOS 10.12.x running homebrew version of rsync 3.1.2 and using `--progress` makes my head spin  watching all the output display in the terminal.

So those coming here from AOL keyword searches,

`rsync -ah --info=progress2 [source] [destination]`

presents the output in a little more sane ‍⚕️ manner IMHO.

Comment: Unfortunately, the output is not very helpful when copying many small files.

Comment: Is there a version of this that uses unison?

Comment: @rustyx I don't recommend replacing `cp` since other programs use it and `cp` flags and behavior is not the same as rsync.

Comment: @Raphael, true, that's why you should use `--info=progress2` rather than `--progress` as suggested by @ipatch in [their comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp#comment1638393_201250)

Comment: If you're using `rsync` to copy files from an ext-* to non ext-* file-system the your results may vary. I couldn't get it to work at all copying to a fat32 external drive.

Comment: @rustyx, I wouldn't suggest that alias.  So long as you remember that -r is included in -a, then sure, but there are occasions that you might not want that.  As per the manpage: `archive mode; equals -rlptgoD`.

Comment: My god! Hard to find this info! Using `--info=progress2`, from above, results in a very nice output like this: `2.21G  99%   4.15MB/s   0:08:26 (xfr#7155, ir-chk=3129/10762)`.

Comment: As @silviot states, the progress shown is just the buffer not the disk, making this useless for example when coping to a USB drive.

Answer (score 119):

I get a kick out of using cURL for this exact purpose. The man page lists the "FILE" protocol as supported, so just use it like any other protocol in a URL:

```
curl -o destination FILE://source
```

Speed, progress, time remaining, and more -- all in a familiar format.

Comment: This is great especially in environments where you are prohibited from installing new tools and where rsync is unavailable.

Comment: Brilliant, this has got to be a must-known hack!

Comment: Nice answer! Clever!

Comment: This presumably has the [same drawback](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/how-to-show-the-transfer-progress-and-speed-when-copying-files-with-cp#comment18577_17279) as `pv`, that it won't save permissions.

Comment: Sweet! any way to make this work for a directory?

Comment: How to do it for a directory?

Comment: `-O` (capital O) to use the source filename instead of having to write destination

Comment: How do I double vote this hack? dumb enough to come back and see I already voted this months ago.

Comment: You could combine this with the find command to get all the files in a directory, but then you would end up getting progress of each file.

Answer (score 115):

If you want to see if your files are transferring correctly you could use `gcp` and `gcp` is like cp but by default gives you a progress bar so that you can see what is being copied. As the program's [wiki notes](http://wiki.goffi.org/wiki/Gcp/en), `gcp` has several useful features such as

> - transfer progression indication
> - continuous copying on error (skip to next file)
> - copy status logging: gcp logs all its actions so that it is possible to know which files have been successfully copied
> - name mangling to handle target filesystem limitations (for example deletion of incompatible characters "*" or "?" on FAT)

However, even when the progress bar has reached 100% when using the tool, you must wait until your terminal prompt reappears before safely removing your media so that you can ensure that the transfer process has successfully finished.

`gcp` is used to copy files and has options such as `--preserve` so that various attributes and permissions can be preserved and `--recursive` so that whole directories can be copied. More information on its options can be found by entering `man gcp` or by going to the [Ubuntu manpages online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gcp.1.html). A tutorial is also available [on this site](http://www.hecticgeek.com/2012/03/gcp-command-line-file-copy-ubuntu-linux/).

Install `gcp` from the repositories with

```
sudo apt-get install gcp
```

(**Note**: in Ubuntu 12.10 the new automount point is, for example, `/media/user/usbdisk`)

You can copy a file to your media by entering

```
gcp /home/mike/file.mp4 /media/usb
```

and copy a folder to your media with

```
gcp -rv ~/Podcasts /media/Mik2
```

Sample output from `gcp` with the progress bar:

```
gcp ~/Videos_incIplayer/mars.flv /media/Mik2
Copying 168.57 MiB 100% |########################################################|   7.98 M/s Time: 00:00:22
```

You can of course specify multiple files or folders to copy to your disk, and there are a lot of other options covered in `man gcp`.

Comment: Got error with it over ssh `dbus.exceptions.DBusException: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11`

Comment: if you have a X11 display open on the machine you can just set `export DISPLAY=:0.0` before starting gcp. If the machine is headless then you'd have to start a xsession into a virtual framebuffer or something, at that point you should probably just look for another program

Comment: `gcp` is pretty decent but the DBUS/X requirement is odd. I handled this over SSH by using ssh forwarding: `ssh -X user@host` and that allowed me to run it.

Comment: Got error `/usr/bin/gcp:42: DeprecationWarning: Importing dbus.glib to use the GLib main loop with dbus-python is deprecated.
Instead, use this sequence:

    from dbus.mainloop.glib import DBusGMainLoop

    DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)
`

Comment: I cannot recommend gcp, 1. it is not maintained. 2. it cannot handle symlinks, hardlinks, etc. 3. it cannot handle sparse file.

Answer (score 68):

There is a tool called `progress` in the repositories that is able to examine various different commands and display progress info for them.

Install it using the command

```
sudo apt-get install progress
```

This tool can be used like that:

```
cp bigfile newfile & progress -mp $!
```

Output:

```
[11471] cp /media/Backup/Downloads/FILENAME.file 
        29.9% (24.2 MiB / 16 MiB)
```

Comment: This is the most up to date answer in my opinion in 2019.

Comment: `progress` is not useful for general scripting, only in a context of `watch`:  a) It needs a fullscreen `tty` and fails with `Error opening terminal: unknown.` else.  Hence you cannot report progress to a pipe to display progress in a CGI environment.  b) Modern shells do not let live zombies long enough, freeing the PID for other processes.  Hence there is a possible race condition where `progress` could monitor the wrong process (i. E. `progress` is loaded via NFS).  c) It is unable to monitor things like `sleep` which is possible with `strace` or `dtrace` and a bit of additional scripting.

Comment: Working in 2021 like a charm, thank you so much

Answer (score 40):

While it doesn't display speed when copying multiple files, the `-v` option to the `cp` command will provide you with progress info. e.g.

```sh
    cp -rv old-directory new-directory
```

Comment: Progress info? This is just verbose output. To provide progress info you would at least need to now how many files, or even which files, needs to be copied.

Comment: It shows what file it is on, which can be enough in less demanding cases.

Answer (score 21):

The kernel knows most of the data such as speed, and often also percentage. Modern kernels expose this via their /proc filesystem.

showspeed from https://github.com/jnweiger/showspeed uses that info. It can attach to already running programs and give periodic updates like this:

```
$ dd if=bigfile of=/tmp/otherbigfile &
$ showspeed dd
dd looks like a process name. pid=4417 matches av0=dd.
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 113MB/s (12%, 2.3GB)  9m:35
p/4417/fd/1w /tmp/otherbigfile 182MB/s (2.6GB)
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 285MB/s (15%, 3.0GB)  8m:08
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 115MB/s (16%, 3.2GB)  8m:01
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 107MB/s (17%, 3.4GB)  7m:39
p/4417/fd/1w /tmp/otherbigfile 104MB/s (3.5GB)
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 139MB/s (19%, 3.7GB)  7m:37
p/4417/fd/0r /home/jw/bigfile 116MB/s (20%, 3.9GB)  7m:18
p/4417/fd/1w /tmp/otherbigfile  67MB/s (4.0GB)
p/4417/fd/1w /tmp/otherbigfile 100MB/s (4.1GB)
...
```

Comment: Nice one. How does it work out percentages though? I guess only in case of file s open as read only? And it will probably not work in case of scattered access.

Comment: In this case you can also use another terminal to run `pkill -USR1 dd` to make `dd` show its status, another option would be `watch -n 1 pkill -USR1 dd` to make it show its progress periodically (every second).

Comment: Right. Many tools got a builtin way to report statistics over time. dd is no exception. Modern implementations have a status=progess option. 

Showspeed is a classic unix style "one tool for one purpose" solution - just like pv. But it has different usecases:

Think of cups pumping a file through ghostscript or you want to know the ETA for an ongoing cp or tar. It might be 95% done already after a few hours and you probably don't want to restart that just to add pv ...

Scattered access would not work well. Showspeed only samples seek positions.

Answer (score 14):

While `pv` can deal with local `cp` tasks, using `dd` with `pv` can deal with both local (`cp`) and remote (`scp`) tasks.

```
dd if=path/to/source.mkv | pv | dd of=path/to/dest.mkv
```

Please ensure the `path/to/dest.mkv` exits by `touch path/to/dest.mkv`

This can show the progress, but if you want the percentage information,

```
dd if=path/to/source.mkv | pv -s 100M | dd of=path/to/dest.mkv
```

Replace `100M` above with the real size of your source file.

### Here Comes the Remote Part

While `scp` can hardly show current progress, using `dd` with `pv` is a piece of cake.

```
ssh onemach@myotherhost dd if=path/to/source.mkv | pv -s 100M | dd of=path/to/dest.mkv
```

Comment: Newer `dd` has `status=progress`: http://askubuntu.com/a/824895/52975

Answer (score 13):

**`dd status=progress`**

Option added in GNU Coreutils 8.24+ (Ubuntu 16.04):

```
dd if=src of=dst status=progress
```

The terminal shows a line of type:

```
462858752 bytes (463 MB, 441 MiB) copied, 38 s, 12,2 MB/s
```

that gets regularly updated.

See also: [How do you monitor the progress of dd?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/215505/how-do-you-monitor-the-progress-of-dd)

Comment: You meant: stdout is a stream of characters and vt100 escape sequences that make your terminal *display* a periodically updated line ;). stdout is always a stream of bytes and has nothing to do with how it is displayed (except that the application can know whether it is currently attached to a terminal or not...)

Comment: @masterxilo newbs won't care, experts will know ;-) hehe

Comment: Well I think it's always good to state things like they are, maybe leaving out some details, but never make your readers produce a wrong mental model. If you say "stdout is a (periodically updated) line" it seems like you are saying stdout is a block of mutable memory which it is not. This is important to know even for newbies.

Answer (score 12):

If you have rsync 3.1 or higher (`rsync --version`), you can copy (cp -Rpn) while preserving permissions and ownership, recurse directories, "no clobber," and display overall progress (instead of just progress by file), copy rate, and (very rough) estimated time remaining with:

```
sudo rsync -a --info=progress2 --no-i-r /source /destination
```

Note that sudo is only needed if dealing with directories/files you don't own. Also, without the `--no-i-r`, the percentage may reset to a lower number at some point during the copy.  Perhaps later versions of rsync will default to no-i-r with info=progress2, but it does not in the current version of 3.1.2.

I've found that the percentage and time remaining are grossly overestimated when copying to a directory that already contains files (ie. like when you would typically use cp -n "no clobber").

Answer (score 11):

There's a new tool called cv that can find any descriptor related to a running command and show progress and speed:
https://github.com/Xfennec/cv

```
cv -w
```

outputs the stats for all running cp,mv etc. operations

Comment: `watch cv -q` is even neater

Comment: It only show progress for an individual files, it does realise whether a `cp` is copying a directory recursively or not.

Comment: It war renamed to progress. Great tool!

Answer (score 10):

There are already some really great answers here, but here are my favorite commands, including my own little spin on the `rsync` command, with my favorite options:

### 1. `watch 'du -hs'` (or, for more granularity: `watch -n 1 'du -sk | awk '\''{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'\'''`) allows you to watch a destination folder grow in size if `cp` is already running:

What if you already started a long `cp` process and don't want to stop it now?

Assuming you already started this copy command:

```bsh
# recursively copy source_dir_name to destination
cp -r source_dir_name destination
```

Just open up a new terminal, with the copy operation already in progress, and run:

```bsh
# cd into destination directory
cd path/to/destination/source_dir_name

# Now watch, live, the size of this destination grow!
watch 'du -hs'

# OR (Preferred!) see even more granularity, in X.xxx MiB: 
watch 'du -sk | awk '\''{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'\'''
```

This will cause the `watch` command to automatically run `du -hs` (or `du -sk | awk '{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'`) every 2 seconds (the default for `watch`) inside your destination directory, so you can see the size of the folder grow in real-time! This doesn't give you a percentage complete, but if you have a rough idea of the size of what you're copying, it certainly gives you something to watch and feel good about, knowing the destination is growing. Here's a sample output on the watch screen:

1. Cmd: `watch 'du -hs'`

   Output:

   > ```bash
   > Every 2.0s: du -hs
   >
   > 2.5G    .
   > ```
2. Cmd: `watch 'du -sk | awk '\''{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'\'''`

   Output:

   > ```bash
   > Every 2.0s: du -sk | awk '{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'
   >
   > 2560.348 MiB .
   > ```

Above, you can see the current size of the current directory (`.`) is 2.5 GiB, or, more specifically in the 2nd case: 2560.348 MiB. To make `watch` use a slower update interval, such as 5 seconds, just add `-n 5` to the `watch` command, like this:

```bsh
watch -n 5 'du -hs'

# OR (preferred, for more granularity)
watch -n 5 'du -sk | awk '\''{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'\'''
```

### 2. `rsync` really is best for this:

My favorite commands:

```bsh
# dry-run
time rsync -rah --dry-run --info=progress2 --stats source destination

# real copy (Important! Do a dry run first and read the
# output summary to ensure you're copying what you intend!)
time rsync -rah --info=progress2 --stats source destination
```

*Note: the `time` part at the front of the above commands just outputs a nice time summary of the total run-time for the operation in the end. This works before any Linux command.*

Here's what an `rsync` `--stats` summary for a `--dry-run` looks like, by the way:

> ```bash
> $ rsync -rah --dry-run --info=progress2 --stats /media/gabriel/cdrom ~/temp
>           2.76G 100% 2570.10GB/s    0:00:00 (xfr#3836, to-chk=0/4837)   
>
> Number of files: 4,837 (reg: 3,836, dir: 1,001)
> Number of created files: 0
> Number of deleted files: 0
> Number of regular files transferred: 3,836
> Total file size: 2.76G bytes
> Total transferred file size: 2.76G bytes
> Literal data: 0 bytes
> Matched data: 0 bytes
> File list size: 0
> File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
> File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
> Total bytes sent: 123.88K
> Total bytes received: 15.54K
>
> sent 123.88K bytes  received 15.54K bytes  278.85K bytes/sec
> total size is 2.76G  speedup is 19,792.78 (DRY RUN)
> ```

### References:

1. Place where I first documented the `watch -n 5 'du -sk | awk '\''{printf "%.3f MiB %s\n", $1/1024, $2}'\'''` type command, in my ROS tutorial: [my ROS.org tutorial: Reading messages from a bag file](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/reading%20msgs%20from%20a%20bag%20file)

### Extra reading:

1. My long answer on some advanced `rsync` usage and stuff: https://superuser.com/questions/1271882/convert-ntfs-partition-to-ext4-how-to-copy-the-data/1464264#1464264
2. [another one of my answers] [Unix & Linux: Is it possible to see cp speed and percent copied?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65077/is-it-possible-to-see-cp-speed-and-percent-copied/567828#567828)

Answer (score 9):

As many said, cp does not include this functionality.

Just to throw my $0.02, what I usually do with trivial copying situations (i.e. no `-R`):

1. See how big the file is and remember
2. Start copying
3. Open another terminal
4. Run `watch ls -lh DIR` on the directory where the target is

This can keep me updated on target file size, with quite a minimum hassle.

As an alternative for less trivial situations, e.g. recursively copying directories, you can use `watch du -hs DIR` to see summary of DIR size.  However du can take long to compute and can even slow down the copying, so you might want to use `-n INTERVAL` argument to watch so that trade-off is acceptable.

**Update:** In case you use wild-cards with command used with watch du, e.g. `watch du -hs backup/*`, don't forget to quote:

```
watch "du -hs backup/*"
```

otherwise the wild-cards will be expanded *only once*, when watch is *started* so du will not look at new files / subdirectories.

Comment: Does not answer the "speed" part, though...

Answer (score 5):

pv knows how to watch file descriptors given a pid, whether it's cp or something else

From the documentation:

```
   (Linux only): Watching file descriptor 3 opened by another process 1234:

          pv -d 1234:3

   (Linux only): Watching all file descriptors used by process 1234:

          pv -d 1234
```

Example:

```
md5sum file &
[1] + 1271 suspended
pv -d 1271
417MiB 0:00:17 [12,1MiB/s] [============>                                 ] 29% ETA 0:00:53

$ cp file.mov copy.mov &
[2] 3731
$ pv -d 3731
3:/media/windows/file.mov:  754MiB 0:00:04 [97,2MiB/s] [======================>                       ] 52% ETA 0:00:07
4:/media/windows/copy.mov:  754MiB 0:00:04 [97,3MiB/s] [     <=>                                                                   ]
```

Comment: This should be incorporated into the selected answer.

Answer (score 4):

Use a shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cp_p()
{
   strace -q -ewrite cp -- "${1}" "${2}" 2>&1 \
      | awk '{
        count += $NF
            if (count % 10 == 0) {
               percent = count / total_size * 100
               printf "%3d%% [", percent
               for (i=0;i<=percent;i++)
                  printf "="
               printf ">"
               for (i=percent;i<100;i++)
                  printf " "
               printf "]\r"
            }
         }
         END { print "" }' total_size=$(stat -c '%s' "${1}") count=0
}
```

This will look like:

```
% cp_p /home/echox/foo.dat /home/echox/bar.dat
66% [===============================>                      ]
```

[Source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-can-i-move-files-and-view-the-progress-e-g-with-a-progress-bar)

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you want to do, Midnight Commander (`mc`) might be the answer. I'm surprised it's not been mentioned yet.

Tools like `pv` or `rsync` are good to display progress of transfer of one huge file, but when it comes to copying whole directories/trees, `mc` calculates the size and then displays the progress very nicely. Plus it's available out of the box on majority of systems.

Comment: "it's available out of the box on majority of systems." ... not on any default Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 2):

one more option to preserve attributes could be (if `source` is a folder it will be created in `destination`)

```
tar -c source | pv -e -t -p -r | tar -C destination  -x
```

hope it may be useful to someone. To have estimated transfer time this can be acheived by doing `do -s source` in advance and passing it as a `-s <size>` parameter to `pv`.

Comment: `-f -` is redundant. `tar`'s default output for `c` and input for `x` are stdout and stdin.

Comment: May it depend on the OS/tar version? I know it’s an Ubuntu site yet this may be useful for other OS owners like macOS

Comment: Nope. All sane implementations (including libarchive's tar, which macOS uses) have this behaviour.

Comment: just verified on macos and your suggestion is perfectly valid - I've updated my answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can monitor your progress using [watch](https://linux.die.net/man/1/watch)

```
cp -r /path/to/your/file/or/dir ./dst
```

and in second terminal you can watch your progress

```
watch -n 0.1 du -h --max-depth=1
```

Comment: This solution works the best for me! Just in case someone wants to know, the second command needs to be run from inside the destination folder.

Answer (score 1):

I use [xcp](https://github.com/tarka/xcp) to get a fancy progress bar:

```
xcp -r myfolder /path/to/dest/folder
```

If you already have rust installed, install it with `cargo install xcp`.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy use any program. At the same time, you can start `sudo iotop` and see the actually disk read/write speed yet without progress.

Comment: Yep, but the OP explicitly asked for a progress bar, so that would be needed...

Answer (score 0):

**Check the source code for progress_bar in the below git repository**

https://github.com/Kiran-Bose/supreme

Also try the custom bash script package **supreme**

Download the deb file and install in debian based distribution or download the source files, modify and use for other distros

Functionality overview

(1)Open Apps
----Firefox
----Calculator
----Settings

(2)Manage Files
----Search
----Navigate
----Quick access

```
            |----Select File(s)
            |----Inverse Selection
            |----Make directory
            |----Make file
                                          |----Open
                                          |----Copy
                                          |----Move
                                          |----Delete
                                          |----Rename
                                          |----Send to Device
                                          |----Properties
```

(3)Manage Phone
----Move/Copy from phone
----Move/Copy to phone
----Sync folders

(4)Manage USB
----Move/Copy from USB
----Move/Copy to USB

Answer (score 0):

As linux original cp has no this functionaliy, I used the following solution to get the progress information:

```
cp -a source_directory destination_direcotry
```

During the copy is working, create another command terminal and go to the source_directory as:

```
cd source_directory
du -sm .
```

After I got the total size of the source_directory, then go to the destination_direcotry to do the same work:

```
cd destination_direcotry
du -sm .
```

I could get the copying progress by comparining the total size difference between the destination_direcotry and the source_directory, the only extra work you need do is opening another terminal besides the cp terminal, to type "du -sm ." to get the total directory size you are coping.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Install gcp

```
sudo apt-get install gcp
```

NOTE: Make Sure you have enable X11 support if not:
Add following line to '/etc/ssh/sshd_config'

```
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

Install

```
sudo apt-get install xauth
reboot
```

When its done:

```
gcp -rv SOURCE_FOLDER DESTINATION_FOLDER
```

or:

```
gcp SOURCE_FILE DESTINATION_FILE
```

Comment: My `sshd` already had this option and `xauth` was installed, I get the error anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Not a perfect option you can open a second terminal and do

```
while true; do ls -lh [location/filename]; sleep 2; clear; done
```

It will show you the file in human readable format and you can watch the size of the file grow larger. I do this when I'm not able to install new utilities on the machine.