# Progress bar or percentage while copying in terminal

Tags: command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Progress and speed with ‘cp’?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp)

Is there a way to enable the **progress bar** while using the `cp` command in terminal?