# command to view the time lapsed

Tags: command-line, files

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Progress and speed with ‘cp’?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp)

I am executing a lot of commands of transferring data in Ubuntu using command line and these are really big file (both in numbers and size). So when I execute the `cp` command, I know the copy is taking place but I am not sure how much has been completed?

Is there some command or an option that I can add to the `cp` command, which will give me the idea how much file transfer has taken place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with plain `cp`. Has been asked many many times.

Use `rsync` instead with the `--progress` option. Works very similar to `cp`, like this:

```
$ rsync --progress sourcefile destinationfile
```

Also, people have been hacking around with wrapping `cp`, like described [here](https://chris-lamb.co.uk/2008/01/24/can-you-get-cp-to-give-a-progress-bar-like-wget/).