# Is there a way to show progress when copying/moving files using the command line?

Tags: command-line

sometimes with large files it takes a while and some sort of progress bar to know that its still working would be nice.

Comment: See also [this related question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp/201292#201292).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rsync --progress $SRC $DEST` can show you the percentage of what has been copied so far.

Answer (score -3):

Try `-v` after the command to do your command in verbose mode.

Comment: as near as I can tell, that doesn't show a progress meter.  Just says "File -> File" and no bar.