# How to check the progress of md5sum on many huge files?

Tags: command-line, md5sum

I have some 500 files of 650MB each, named `bigfile.000` to `bigfile.199` and I need to calculate the MD5 checksum of all files combined.  The command I am using is:

```
cat bigfile.* | md5sum
```

I have the time, and I understand it will take hours to complete, but I still want to check the progress.  Is there any way to do so?  Like piping something in between and do a word count that doesn't affect performance much?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Progress and speed with 'cp'?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp)

Comment: I think it's not a duplicate question - they are different questions but simply the same answer that solves two different problems. `cp` is different from `cat` anyway.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `pv`. It is in the repos, and shows a nice progress bar.

```
pv bigfile.* | md5sum
```

should do what you want.

Answer (score 5):

Progress bar plus stats: ETA, ...:

```
pv -pteIrabT file | md5sum
```

For example:

```
# pv -pteIrabT hugefile.tar.lzo | sha1sum 
7.59GiB {----} 0:03:22 [39.1MiB/s] [38.5MiB/s] [>                          ]  7% ETA 0:41:47 ETA 19:45:26
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to give any more output than just using `pv` without any options.