# Is there any advanced MOVE command with GUI-kinda interface

Tags: command-line, wget, mv

While downloading a file,in command-line, we have WGET which shows us the progress of the download. Similarly, is there any command which gives us visual status of the process(move).

Comment: Not `mv` per se, but close: http://askubuntu.com/q/17275/158442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**rsync**: Rsync moves files with `--remove-source-files` and has a `-P` switch for a progress bar. So if you have rsync installed, you could use a simple alias in your shells dotfile:

```
alias mv='rsync -aP --remove-source-files'
```

... although rsync might be a bit slower.

Adapted from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2577/how-can-i-move-files-and-view-the-progress-e-g-with-a-progress-bar)

Comment: Nice. You should add that to http://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp, which has some other alternatives as well.

Comment: The OP was clear: move, not copy...

Comment: Edited answer accordingly

Comment: If he wants to view progress when moving files, I suspect that he's actually "moving" them between two different file systems. If this is the case, than "move" is really "copy+remove".