# How to copy and paste files with CLI and have a status

Tags: command-line, cp, paste, statusbar

I am trying to copy large amounts of data using SSH so all I have is the CLI.  I am using the `cp -a /source/* /dest/` method but I can't tell how fast it is copying or what the progress is.  Is there anything I can add to this command to see this info?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen OP's connecting via SSH, but all the copying is done on the remote system itself from what I can tell.

Comment: I would still use rsync, more with large files as it eliminates duplication of effort.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen that's the third suggestion in http://askubuntu.com/questions/17275/progress-and-speed-with-cp

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggesting using `rsync` instead:

```
rsync -aP /source/* /dest/
```

It's the `P` argument here doing most of the magic. It should show you an accurate enough progress report for each file.