# Copying multiple files with progress

Tags: command-line, cp, coreutils

I want to be able to copy multiple files from multiple USB flash disks at the same time, being able to see current transfer rate of each simultaneously. It is part of performance testing for USB port on a specific board.

Using `pv source > /dev/null` from [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/17279), I am able to see the current transfer rate for one file. However, when I use `pv source > /dev/null &` to send the process into background and be able to run another transfer, the output from the pv command is not shown on stdout anymore.

It is to be noted that I am using minicom to connect to remote host using serial port, as the target board does not have it's own console output.

I am open to suggestions other than pv as well. The task is to do performance/bandwidth test of the USB port. I originally wanted to do it with cp but found out that it does not provide current transfer rate. I do not have a GUI otherwise could try it from that

EDIT: I have 2 problems with rsync:
1) The transfer rate is very slow (one-third of what I get with pv)
2) It somehow deletes the /dev/null after transferring around 300 MB, thus, stopping with an error

Comment: I also see that `pv` seems not to allow redirection of *stderr* as well as it does not display it when running in background... Strange. But you could still just open multiple terminals (or tabs in one terminal) and run all instances in foreground, one per each window.

Comment: @ByteCommander I have only one serial port available so can't open multiple terminals. Setting up ethernet and SSH can be one option though, which I already am working on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been able to answer this question by using ssh.

As I can see the transfer rate of one transfer with `pv source > /dev/null`, I set up multiple ssh sessions and executed one transfer per session

Comment: I originally left a post, but I think it made more sense to put it in a comment instead.. 
Instead of creating an ssh session for each transfer you are doing, you can just as easily use screen or tmux. Both of these are terminal multiplexers which will save you time when managing multiple terminal sessions.