# What is the accelerate method of free space wiping with random fill?

Tags: security, disk-usage, openssl, storage, secure-erase

I am currently [using `sfill`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/sfill.1.html) to wipe free space in my root partition ( `/dev/sdaX`). Its default setting is a 38 pass `sudo sfill -v directory/mountpoint` but its taking hours to complete this step. I then tried to use less secure three pass method `sudo sfill -lv directory/mountpoint` the problem is its taking fairly the same amount of time to wipe free space as the default. It is due to `dev/urandom` which peaks at 13MB/s. While searching for an alterntive method to speed up free space wiping step, I reached this [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/72238/282036) which uses `openssl` to randomize the wipe.

```
 openssl rand $(</proc/partitions awk '$4=="sda" {print $3*1024}') >/dev/sda
```

Is this a good way to wipe free space in root drive or other safer method exists? In the above command `sda` is our root partion `sdaX`, right?

Comment: On my machine `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M count=1000 | pv >/dev/null` shows that /dev/urandom runs at least at 170MB/s (about 5 seconds/GB). `dd if=/dev/urandom bs=1M of=/somebigfile` is about as fast as you can get.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, [wiping your drive 35+ times](https://www.howtogeek.com/115573/htg-explains-why-you-only-have-to-wipe-a-disk-once-to-erase-it/) is completely unnecessary. The Guttmann Method (35 wipes) is something designed to wipe *any* drive, from brand-new modern spinning drives to massive ancient 5MB behemoths that are more likely to store resident data. With that said, wiping your drive once or twice is pretty much the best you can do. You have a modern magnetic drive.

The `sfill` command is... silly. See the manpage for what I mean. If you only need to wipe the drive out with zeros, you can just use the (far simpler) `sfill -llz /path/to/your/mountpoint` to wipe out all free space with zeros, once. This (according to Guttmann himself, see above link as well [as right here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/961558/how-to-know-the-progress-of-sfill-free-space-wiping-process)) is more than good enough for the vast majority of systems. As you're writing zeros instead of random data, your only speed limit will be your drive's speed.

If you need plausible deniability ("No, officer, I didn't wipe this hard drive"), you can use  the sister command `sfill -ll /path/to/your/mountpoint` to wipe your drive in a single pass with random data. This will be slower, but just as secure for your system as any other wiping method with the addition of possible plausible deniability.

However, if you ***really*** need to ensure that no data is absolutely recoverable from this drive (in theory or otherwise), use a drill.

Comment: For true data disposal, I advise dropping the drive in molten metal ala Terminator style so the physical disk itself cannot be read. If data is truly sensitive, I would not take the easy route in absence of known data recovery methods. See: https://hsmr.cc/palinopsia/ ; as for actual discussion, is DBAN no longer the preferred method for drive wiping?

Comment: @avisitoritseems DBAN is still a great tool for this sort of thing, as long as you don't mind the reboot. Feel free to use it - it's secure, fast, and extremely reliable.