# Is there a copy handling progam available that can queue, pause and resume?

Tags: software-recommendation, files, clipboard

Is there a copy handling progam available for ubuntu? Something similar to Copy Handler on Windows which can queue, pause and resume files being copied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Possibly a [duplicate question?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17274/how-to-pause-resume-transfer-of-large-files)

If you want a GUI version try [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/)

[image]

N.B. in the download section there is a deb file you can download.  Remember - the software is very new.

Comment: This as a file manager plugin for nautilus would be great.

Answer (score 4):

> Helps you to integrate UltraCopier on the Nautilus/Nemo file browser.

---

**Ultracopier:**

Is included on the official ubuntu universe repo and is added as a dependency of the extension, so will be automatically installed.

**After install:** Select one option

- Restart your computer(recommended)
- Logout and login
- Execute for:

  Nemo: `nemo -q` (save your work first)

  Nautilus: `nautilus -q` (save your work first)

**To configure your keyboard shortcut**

Rigth click on the desktop and then in Configure UltraCopier.

**To install on ubuntu 14.04:**

For Nemo:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extensions
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nemo-ultracopier
```

For Nautilus:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extensions
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nautilus-ultracopier
```

**To remove:**

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:lestcape/ultracopier-extension
```

For Nemo:

```
sudo apt-get purge nemo-ultracopier
```

For Nautilus:

```
sudo apt-get purge nautilus-ultracopier
```

**Report any problem:**

https://github.com/lestcape/Nautilus-UltraCopier-Extension

https://github.com/lestcape/Nemo-UltraCopier-Extension

Comment: Nice work I also tried to interate it to nautilus int last year using bash but failed. Also palyed with minicopier for nautilus but wor only through nautilis-scripts !!

Comment: totti, i suppose that you don't understand the linux clipboard, as this is the only  requirements. I complicate the thing, because i want to provide a shortcut key and also override the nautilus one, so i need to do some hacking here... If you want the nautilus-script, without the hack (of course) is there (for Nemo): https://github.com/lestcape/Nemo-UltraCopier

Comment: I'm also tried to make shortcut key for the paste operation. Plan : user select files in nautilus and press copy. now they have 2 options, 1. paste using nautilus copy manager (ctrl + V) or using minicoier ( ctrl + shitf + V ). the difficult part is to identify current nautilus path reliabily. I used dbus for that . But dbus seems to alter its behavair over OS versions.

Comment: I started like you, only i took a different way. I read first the Nemo code, and how the people do his extensions, then i contact the ultracopy author. Two people are better than one. The rest of the story is here: https://github.com/alphaonex86/Ultracopier/issues/8

Answer (score 0):

[Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/) is a Total-Commander-like two-panel manager.

`F5` or `F6` open dialog for copying or moving files, where instead of confirming and running the job immediately, you can press `F2` to send the job to a queue where you can manage it further.

Answer (score 0):

I actually just use `scp` on the terminal for this.

If you select a bunch of files / directories in nautilus and copy them, you can paste them into a text editor- they'll end up as paths separated by newlines. I just append `\` to the end of each line, replace `%20` with `\`  and add quotes if necessary (note the space after the slash), prefix with `scp` or `cp` and away you go: paste into a terminal, hit enter and you have serial copy.

eg:

```
scp
networkserver:/some/dir/file1 \
networkserver:/some/other/dir/file2 \
"networkserver:/some/other/badly\ named\ dir/file3" \
.
```