# How can I queue file operations?

Tags: nautilus, optimization, transfer, defrag

When I pick and choose files to copy to or from a single device, Nautilus accumulates file operations in parallel:

[image: File Operations]

I worry that in certain circumstances this could cause fragmentation of the destination device, or transfer slowdowns due to scattered reads on the source device and increased network connection overhead.

How can I queue these file operations instead, so that each operation starts only after the previous one has finished?

Comment: I would think the whole idea of parallel transfer was made to speed things up. Maybe you find out, whether it is worth worrying at all, before trying to circumvent this parallel invocation? Maybe the ChangeLog of the project has some information?

Comment: `cp <Source1> <Dest1>; cp <Source2> <Dest2>` :P.

Comment: @userunknown AFAIK the point of parallel transfer is not to speed things up, but to be agnostic about the priority of items copied. For example, a user might copy 20 GB of music files, then decide to copy a 10 kB text file. If queuing were enabled by default, then the user would have to wait for the music to copy before copying the small text file. If parallel copying occurs with the same source or destination drive, then it *will* slow down the process, since the read/write/transfer is competing. There might be special cases (e.g. SSD is the shared drive) where it wouldn't make a difference.

Comment: @Sparhawk You're right. In most cases *sequential* writes being interrupted because of others being run simultaneously make them run as random writes and slow down transfer rates dramatically. However, when copying from multiple separate physical drive, this can be advantageous as it *can* read/write in parallel in such a case.

Comment: For KDE users reading this, this is [feature request #259512](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259512)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See if this related question and its answer can help you: [Is there a copy handling progam available that can queue, pause and resume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42676/is-there-a-copy-handling-progam-available-that-can-queue-pause-and-resume)

It suggests using an application other that *Nautilus*, that AFAIK cannot do what you ask.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 nice GUI programs:

1. [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) [[deb [image: Install ultracopier]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/ultracopier)]
2. [MiniCopier](http://www.adriancourreges.com/projects/minicopier/) [[java](http://www.adriancourreges.com/projects/minicopier/#dl-section)]

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an answer, but can you please provide a brief description of each app, including the pros and cons of each, as well as instructions for installing on Ubuntu and links where the OP can find out more about each?

Comment: Unfortunately none of these integrates with Nautilus

Answer (score 0):

MATEs file-manager Caja queues transfers by default.
Alternatively GNOME-commander or Double Commander or mc probably queues by default.