# Enqueue Nautilus file operations

Tags: nautilus, transfer, gvfs

Copying (or moving) files in parallel can degrade so much the performance.

I usually need to copy large amount of files over network using the nautilus (using stuff like `smb://` or `sftp://` urls).

The answer for similar questions before only handle in disk operations only, not for stuff mounted in nautilus. I tried to use Ultracopier (from this answer [How can I queue file operations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44725/how-can-i-queue-file-operations)) and using the ~/.gvfs/ folder but it generates error (operation not supported).

So how can I enqueue Nautilus operations with all the options I have using the nautilus (like networking and all `gvfs` mounts)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the current version of ultracopier on ubuntu is really old (more than 5 years).

Please see:
http://forum-ultracopier.first-world.info/post2448.html?hilit=compile#p2448

This will be helpfully to integrate ultracopier to nautilus, if you compile a new ultracopier version from the source code:
[Is there any special software for copy,cut like operations?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93231/is-there-any-special-software-for-copy-cut-like-operations/554813#554813)