# how to handle large file copies

Tags: software-recommendation, files

I would like to know how I can manage copying large files of the order of 20Gb and all in ubuntu. I mean is there any copy handler software as in windows. I need to pause/resume my copy and add more files to the queue. Please tell me how to.

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at this question: [Is there a copy handling progam available that can queue, pause and resume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42676/is-there-a-copy-handling-progam-available-that-can-queue-pause-and-resume)

The application [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) is recommended there.